# SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT  DISTINCT id FROM "tickets"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I really don't think the title of this explains well of what I'm trying to do but I'm not even sure how to ask.

So I have `ticket has_many tasks` and `task belongs_to account`. I've this as a scope to return the ticket listing where an tickets task belongs to an account:

```
scope :for_tasks_account, lambda { |account| joins(:tasks => :account ).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id) }
```

but it's returning multiple of the same ticket because a ticket has multiple tasks that the account belongs to.

How can I get it to only return each ticket once rather for each task in that ticket that an account belongs to?

Thanks!

## Update

I'd actually like to combine to scopes to list all that apply to the two lambdas:

```
scope :for_account, lambda { |account| joins(:group => :accounts ).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id) } || lambda { |account| joins(:tasks => :account ).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id) }
```

Is this possible? As well as the first issue.

## Update 2

I've figured out how to get both of the queries to be combined but I'm still getting multiple of the same ticket in the returned query.

```
  scope :for_group_with_account, lambda { |account| joins(:group => :accounts ).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id) }
  scope :for_task_with_account, lambda { |account| joins(:tasks => :account ).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id) }
  scope :for_account, lambda { |account| for_group_with_account(account) & for_task_with_account(account).select('DISTINCT id') }
```

I'm using `DISTICNT` but I still get

```
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT  DISTINCT id FROM "tickets" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "tickets"."group_id" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "groups"."id" = "assignments"."group_id" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "assignments"."account_id" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "tasks"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id" INNER JOIN "accounts" "accounts_tasks" ON "accounts_tasks"."id" = "tasks"."account_id" WHERE ("tickets"."archived" IS NULL) AND (accounts.id = 20) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use "distinct" in this scenario.

```
scope :for_tasks_account, lambda { |account| joins(:tasks => :account ).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id).select('distinct accounts.id') }
```

Comment: Ok with that I get `SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT  distinct id FROM "tickets" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "tasks"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "tasks"."account_id" WHERE ("tickets"."archived" IS NULL) AND (accounts.id = 20) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0`

Comment: try scope :for_tasks_account, lambda { |account| joins(:tasks => :account ).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id).select('distinct accounts.id') }